# is java.util observer safe on a (static) grails (2.5) service?

Tags: grails, observer-pattern

We have decoupled certain events by implementing listeners in exploded plugins (i.e. outside of the core application).  Then we can build different implementations.  Also, the listeners work must be outside any transaction, as it can take a long time (think connecting to the internet and waiting a long time, and if if fails, it must not rollback anything).  The app is a webapp and api running on tomcat.

The problem is setChanged().

Here is a service:

```
class someService extends Observable {

}
```

Here is a plugin bootstrap:

```
 SomeService someService
 :
 someService.addObserver(listenerService)
```

Here is the listener:

```
class ListenerService implements Observer {
@NotTransactional
void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
     DomainObject domainObject (DomainObject) arg
     // do somethign which takes a very log time
}
```

Here it is being called somewhere (e.g inside a method of someService, or elsewhere)

```
someService.setChanged()
someService.notifyObservers(someEvent)
```

I see a big problem here - if the setChanged is called my multiple requests, Each will set changed=true, but the first notifyObserver will set it to false, so when the second notifyObserer executes, it will see changed == false and return.

I see 2 possible solutions:

1. Put the observer on a domain object, which is not static.
2. hook into the afterUpdate domain event (not idea as we want to be outside the transaction, but we could start anther thread and do the work asynchronously)

Does anyone know if using the observer on the domain object (and calling setChanged and nofityObservers in some session) is a good solution?